# React Native : update context throw "Cannot update during an existing state transition"

Tags: react-native, expo, react-context, react-native-ui-kitten

I have a react native app and i'm trying to update a Date in a custom context.

ThemeContext

```js
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
    theme: 'dark',
    toggleTheme: () => { },
    date: new Date(),
    setDate: (date: Date) => { } 
});
```

> Basic context with the date and the function to update it

App.tsx

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      theme: 'dark',
      date: new Date()
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { theme, date } = this.state;
    const currentTheme = themes[theme];

    const toggleTheme = () => {
      const nextTheme = theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
      this.setState({ theme: nextTheme });
    };

    const setDate = (date: Date) => {
      // ERROR is raised HERE
      this.setState({date: date});
    }

    return (
      <>
        <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme, date, setDate }}>
          ...
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

> I simply hava a state with a Date and create a setDate function. I wrapped my app into the context provider.

Picker

```js
class PickerContent extends React.Component<{}, ContentState> {
    static contextType = ThemeContext;

    constructor(props: {} | Readonly<{}>) {
        super(props);
        let currentMode = 'date';
        let show = false;

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            currentMode = 'datetime';
            show = true;
        }

        this.state = {
            date: new Date(),
            mode: currentMode,
            show: show
        };
    }

    setMode(currentMode: string) {
        this.setState({ mode: currentMode, show: true });
    };

    onChange(_event: any, selectedDate: Date) {
        const currentDate = selectedDate || this.state.date;
        // I update the context here
        this.context.setDate(currentDate);
        
        this.setState({date: currentDate, show: Platform.OS === 'ios'})
    }

    render() {
        const {show, date, mode } = this.state;
        const color = 'dark';

        return (
            <>
            ...
            {show && <DateTimePicker
                ...
                onChange={(event, selectedDate) => this.onChange(event, selectedDate)}>
        </DateTimePicker>}</>
        )
    }
}
```

> I use the lib 'DateTimePicker' to choose a date and bind the onChange to update the context. This picker is on a modal.

So the warning appears when the `onChange` function of DateTimePicker is trigger. The error is on the `setState` of `App.tsx` (in setDate)

`Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render'). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

Would you know how to correct this error?

EDIT :

I was using a Modal component from the UI Kitten library. I switch to the react native Modal and the error is gone. It seems that the error comes from the Library. SORRY

thank you in advance for your help,
Sylvain

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @Konstantin I, i edited my question, the error finally seems to come from the library used for the Modal component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my question. The error finally seems to come from the library used (ui kitten).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using class component, what you can do is to move the context update fn inside `componentDidUpdate`. You just compare your states, if your state has changed, you update your context with the new value.
Something along the lines of:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.date !== this.state.date) {
    this.context.setDate(this.state.date);
  }
}

onChange(_event: any, selectedDate: Date) {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || this.state.date;
    
    this.setState({date: currentDate, show: Platform.OS === 'ios'})
}
```

This way you're not updating your context during render.

If you refactor this component to functional, you would be able to do the same thing using `useEffect`.

Comment: I, thanks for your answer. I tried to do what you said but i have the same error. The error It's happening inside the App component not the Picker. So i think the mistake is on the app class

Comment: It was my understanding that you pointed to the line of `setDate` inside your picker. I cannot know which line brings you the problem, so please update your question accordingly.

Comment: I said at then end of my question : "So the warning appears when the onChange function of DateTimePicker is trigger. The error is on the setState of App.tsx (in setDate)". isn't it clear?

Comment: I update the code to see which line exactly raised the error

Comment: I revised your code again, why do you have your fns inside render? Please convert them to methods (remove the `consts`, you are using Class, not Functional component), move them outside of Render, pass them using the `this` to your context, and please tell me the result of combining this plus the previous answer.